# Is there a way to see the current log file in RubyMine?

Tags: ruby, logging, rubymine

I think it would be great to be able to see log/development.log and maybe log/test.log in the same way you see the output of a running task or tests in RubyMine. Is it possible?

Answer (score 3):

You can add it in Run Configurations | Logs:

[image]

Actually it's added automatically but the title (Server Log) is a little bit confusing. We'll fix it the future version

Comment: Generally when running the server I get the log to stdout or I'm getting the server log automatically and I see it in RubyMine, in it's Run window. But I'd like to see the log for when I run rake tasks that generate log messages.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for the test log specifically, edit the configuration for the appropriate test or spec under `Rake` on the left side of the `Edit Configurations` dialog. Then go to the `Logs` tab and click the plus button under the empty listing. Locate the log file log/test.log and call it "Test Log".